# Start service from alarm manager not working

Tags: android, service, background, alarmmanager, native

I have read many more similar questions to this in stackoverflow but I couldn't solve my problem.
I want to trigger an android service at 3.45p.m of every day.For that I used an AlarmManager which starts the service as follows.

**Application class**

```
public class AppSettings extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        scheduleAlarm();
    }


    public void scheduleAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UploadService.class);
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);

        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pIntent);
    }


}
```

**Service class**

```
public class UploadService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("MyAlarmService", "onCreate");
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand Called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
// Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
        } else {
            //deprecated in API 26
            v.vibrate(500);
        }
        stopSelf();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onBind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("MyAlarmService", "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onUnbind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }
}
```

**Manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.softarena.photosapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".app.AppSettings"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logoo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logoo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
        <activity android:name=".views.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".views.PhotoDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".views.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".views.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".views.SignUpActivity" />

        <service
            android:name="com.softarena.photosapp.services.UploadService"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

when I run the app the my phone is `onStartCommand` is getting called but only when the app is open.if I close the app and wait until `onStartCommand` getting called it is not working.I am using a *Nokia 8 device which runs android 9*.I tried starting alarm manager with `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` and `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` also considering Doze mode but there is no way to repeat the alarm with these 2 methods and if app is closed `onStartCommand` not getting called.
Is this a device problem or is there anything wrong with my code?

**Edit:** Can I  use a WorkManager or a JobScheduler to achieve my requirement?

Comment: I have tried some ways(Service, Pending Intent, Work-Manager), nothing works in all devices. Everything works in android version<8[haven't tested in 8], no matter app is open or close or killed. But in android 9,10 or above these only works when app is open or in background.

Comment: @Unknown_2433 ok then isn't there a way to achieve my requirement in android 9,10 devices?

Comment: No[for all android version](As far as I have tried)